Not able to use the right side drawer navigation in react native
So I am new to react native and have been trying to implement drawer navigators.
The issue I am facing is that when I click on the icon on the right side I want the right side drawer to open but it does not seem to be working and instead only opens the left side drawer. I want to maintain these icons only and implement drawer navigation in them. I have set the value of drawerPosition to right in the second navigator which is inside the Drawer.Navigator.
Here is the code I have implemented.
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import SignUpScreen from './SignUpScreen';
import SignInScreen from './SignInScreen';
import Watchlist from './Watchlist';
import AlgoTrader from './AlgoTrader';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio';
import Insights from './Insights';
import Home from './Home';
import Welcome from './Welcome';

import Hamburger from "../Assets/Hamburger";
import ProfilePhoto from "../Assets/ProfilePhoto";
import HomeActive from '../Assets/HomeActive';
import HomeInactive from '../Assets/HomeInactive';
import WatchlistActive from '../Assets/WatchlistActive';
import WatchlistInactive from '../Assets/WatchlistInactive';
import AlgoTraderActive from '../Assets/AlgoTraderActive';
import AlgoTraderInactive from '../Assets/AlgoTraderInactive';
import PortfolioActive from '../Assets/PortfolioActive';
import PortfolioInactive from '../Assets/PortfolioInactive';
import InsightsActive from '../Assets/InsightsActive';
import InsightsInactive from '../Assets/InsightsInactive';

const insightsData = "NIFTY";
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const ProfileDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const CustomDrawerContent = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Left drawer</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const CustomRightDrawerContent = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Right Drawer</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const ProfileTabNavigator = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const navigation1 = useNavigation();


  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        initialParams={{ title: "Home1", customProp: insightsData }}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "Home",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation1.openDrawer()}>
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Home</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => (
            focused ? <HomeActive width={25} height={25} /> : <HomeInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />



       <Tab.Screen
        name="Watchlist"
        component={Watchlist}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "FTSM Watchlist",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} >
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Watchlist</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => (
            focused ? <WatchlistActive width={25} height={25} /> : <WatchlistInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />


       <Tab.Screen
        name="Algo Trader"
        component={AlgoTrader}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "Algo Traders",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} >
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Algo Trader</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => (
            focused ? <AlgoTraderActive width={25} height={25} /> : <AlgoTraderInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />



       <Tab.Screen
        name="Portfolio"
        component={Portfolio}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "My Portfolio",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} >
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Portfolio</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => (
            focused ? <PortfolioActive width={25} height={25} /> : <PortfolioInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />


       <Tab.Screen
        name="Insights"
        component={Insights}
        initialParams={{ data: insightsData }}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "Insights",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} >
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Insights</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => (
            focused ? <InsightsActive width={25} height={25} /> : <InsightsInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />

    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const ProfileDrawerNavigator = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (

    
    <ProfileDrawer.Navigator drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}>
      <ProfileDrawer.Screen name=" " component={ProfileTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: true, drawerPosition:"left" }} />
    </ProfileDrawer.Navigator>

  );
};

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={CustomRightDrawerContent} >
      <Drawer.Screen name=" " component={ProfileDrawerNavigator} options={{ headerShown: true, drawerPosition:"right" }} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;



You can follow up with Official documentation a bit more thoroughly. You can find it here.
const DrawerExample = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    ScreenFirst: { screen: ScreenFirst },
    ScreenTwo: { screen: ScreenTwo }
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: "right",
    drawerWidth: 100
  }
);

Use this setup for the position change. You can get more perspective from here
